# Method call is nonstandard extension

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

When I have this code in a jsp file,

```
 <a href="${item.url}${item.type.contains("front")?"?isFrontPage=1":""}"></a>
```

Intellij complains about `contains` method.

> method call is nonstandard extension
>
> This inspection reports possible EL problems, caused by usage of nonstandard EL extensions
>    e.g. usage of JSF EL expressions outside attribute or using nonstandard EL expressions

The `item.url` and `item.type` are all String, and when the code executed the result is OK.

And the code completion is also ok... As a matter of fact, the `contains`method is popped when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd>. So intellij knows `item.type` is a String object.

What is wrong? thanks.

Comment: Are the smart quotes in your original code?

Comment: @shmosel Sorry it is typo, I have edited the code.